# Redefinition of page size fails

Tags: paper-size

Hans has [coded a nice little piece of TeX](https://raw.github.com/zem/pQSL/master/pqsl.cls) that generates the back of QSL cards (cards sent from one Ham operator to another validating the previous contact made between them).

Hans' code prints on paper cards, but I'd very much like to print them on my shiny new Brother Q-Touch Label printer which uses 62mm wide "endless" strips of adhesive paper. Sadly, I can't seem to reach Hans so I need to ask you.

I have tried adjusting some of the page-size definitions but the layout completely falls apart. Could someone be so kind and help me in adjusting the page size of the output so that it fits on a piece of paper 62mm wide? Feel free to move the "Vy 73..." line or discard it, I can very well manually write that when I sign the card anyway.

Here's Hans' code so you don't have to copy and paste it yourself (all credits to Hans, https://github.com/zem/):

```
\ProvidesClass{pqsl}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[papersize={14.8cm,10.5cm}, margin=0.0cm, marginratio=1:1]{geometry}


\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\newcommand\MYPIC[1]{\newcommand{\@MYPIC}{#1}}
\newcommand\MYHAMORGPIC[1]{\newcommand{\@MYHAMORGPIC}{#1}}
\newcommand\MYHAMORGNAME[1]{\newcommand{\@MYHAMORGNAME}{#1}}
\newcommand\MYCALL[1]{\newcommand{\@MYCALL}{#1}}
\newcommand\MYNAME[1]{\newcommand{\@MYNAME}{#1}}
\newcommand\MYQTH[1]{\newcommand{\@MYQTH}{#1}}
\newcommand\MYMAIDEN[1]{\newcommand{\@MYMAIDEN}{#1}}


\newcommand{\@CALL}{}
\newcommand{\@VIA}{}
\newcommand{\@DATE}{}
\newcommand{\@TIME}{}
\newcommand{\@BAND}{}
\newcommand{\@MODE}{}
\newcommand{\@RST}{}

\newcommand{\@qslcardback}[7][]{
    \newpage
    \renewcommand{\@CALL}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\@VIA}{#2}
    \renewcommand{\@DATE}{#3}
    \renewcommand{\@TIME}{#4}
    \renewcommand{\@BAND}{#5}
    \renewcommand{\@MODE}{#6}
    \renewcommand{\@RST}{#7}

    \ \vspace{0.5cm}

    \hspace{0.5cm}
    %%%BEGIN left upper Minipage with MYCALL and locator
    \begin{minipage}{5.2cm}

    {\Huge \textbf{\@MYCALL}}

    \smallskip
    \@MYNAME \\
    \@MYQTH \\
    \@MYMAIDEN
    \end{minipage}
    %%%END left upper Minipage with MYCALL and locator
    %%% BEGIN Centered upper Minipage with hamorgpic
    \begin{minipage}{2cm}
    \centering \includegraphics[width=1cm]{\@MYHAMORGPIC}

    \footnotesize \@MYHAMORGNAME
    \end{minipage}
    %%% END centered upper Minipage with hamorgpic
    \hfill
    %%%BEGIN Right upper Minipage with QSO and Via Fields 
    \begin{minipage}{5.5cm} % very ugly hack with \vphantom ;)
    \framebox[5.5cm][l]{\scriptsize QSO WITH: \vphantom{$\rule[-1mm]{0mm}{6mm}$} \bf \Large{\@CALL}}
    \smallskip
    \framebox[5.5cm][l]{\scriptsize VIA:\hspace{10mm} \vphantom{$\rule[-1mm]{0mm}{6mm}$} \bf \Large{\@VIA}}
    \end{minipage}
    %%%END Right upper Minipage with QSO and Via Fields 
    \hspace{0.5cm}

    \vspace{1.5cm}

    \hspace{0.5cm}I am pleased to confirm the following QSO:
    \topsep3pt
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \bf\quad Date (Y-M-D) \quad & \bf\ Time (UTC)\ &\bf\quad Band\quad&\bf\ Mode\ &\bf\ RST\bf\ \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \vphantom{$\dfrac b b$}\bf \@DATE & \bf \@TIME & \bf \@BAND & \bf \@MODE & \bf \@RST \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \smallskip

    \end{center}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \hspace{0.5cm}vy 73 de \makebox[3.5cm]{\dotfill}
}



\newcommand{\@qslcardfront}[7][]{
    \newpage
    %That Hack with the Paperwith .799 is important to get an 
    % exact number of pics, the front needs to be smaller than 
    % the paper
    % \paperwidth \paperheight
    \includegraphics[width=14.799cm,height=10.499cm]{\@MYPIC}
}

\newcommand{\@qslcardbothsides}[7][]{
    \@qslcardfront[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}
    \@qslcardback[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}
}

\newcommand\qslcard\@qslcardbothsides


\DeclareOption{front}{
    \renewcommand\qslcard\@qslcardfront
}
\DeclareOption{back}{
    \renewcommand\qslcard\@qslcardback
}
\ProcessOptions
```

Because I was asked, these are the solemn contents of the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[back]{pqsl}

\input{config}

\begin{document}
\input{contacts}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I use the pdfscreen package to create odd sizes.

Comment: I can adjust the size of the page just fine - the problem here is that any change in paper size also re-adjusts anything on the page, ie. the location of this changes dramatically.

Comment: I believe this is a cls file, rather than a tex file.  Anyway, TeX doesn't deal directly with printers.  These days one typically generates PDF output and uses Adobe Reader to print the document.  So instead of messing with the code, just figure out how to get Reader to fit the given page size to your printer.

Comment: I can do that (and have done it), but the printout becomes extremely small - as the height of the printout is halfed. I'd much rather re-arrange the layout istself so that most of the sizes can stay the same, just appear elsewhere on the page.

Comment: I've never done a cls file, and I don't know how it is used.  Do you have anything that says \begin{document)?

Comment: Of course, sorry for not posting that in the beginning. I have edited my request accordingly. Hope this helps... ;)

Comment: @Christian Without an example of what's in `config.tex` and `contacts.tex` it's impossible to say anything: I guess that `contacts.tex` is written in some special way.

Comment: We don't need the whole contacts file.  one example will do.  (That's why they call it a Minimal Working Example.)